# Проблема с INSERT запросом mysql2 javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

немогу правильно прописать sytax не понимаю в чем ошибка?
использоваю https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый Genesis. Вы на сайте больше года, 13 вопросов - почитайте пожалуйста, наконец, справку о том, как правильно задавать вопросы и как оформлять текст кода или текст ошибки в вопросе. Как и сами вопросы

Comment: Благодарю, извиняюсь, исправлюсь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли кавычки. Попробуйте так:

`` `INSERT INTO contacts (name, number) VALUES ('${req.body.name}', '${req.body.number}')` ``

Comment: Спасибо, вроде так тоже пробовал но завтра с утра проверю 